# Why can't I access sub-elements of an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm guessing this has probably been answered a million times, but I don't have the right language to describe this particular issue. Essentially I can't do something like `$ctrl.thing.subelement`. The following works just fine:

```
<div class="col-md-10" ng-repeat="p in $ctrl.patient">
  <!--Body content-->
  <p>{{p.name}}</p>
  <p>{{p.id}}</p>
</div>
```

This prints the patient name and id -- the behavior I want -- except I don't have the need for a repeat. I want to be able to reference specific `patient` elements throughout the page.

Similarly, this will print all the patient's information as JSON plaintext (that's how everything is stored).

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <!--Body content-->
  <p>{{$ctrl.patient}}</p>
</div>
```

What doesn't work is the following (which is what I really want)

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <!--Body content-->
  <p>{{$ctrl.patient.name}}</p>
  <p>{{$ctrl.patient.id}}</p>
</div>
```

What am I missing here? Why am I able to access `$ctrl.patient` in a div but not `$ctrl.patient.name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple because $ctrl.patient is not an object representing a single patient it is an array of patients – which is why you iterate over it. So you need to know which item in the array you want to access by index and then use:

```
{{$ctrl.patient[0].name}}
```

Where `0` is the index of the record you want.

Comment: I knew the answer was something painfully simple. You are a god send.